# Simple tool to create an MSI

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer

Our company release a new version every month, with the latest data. We currently supply a CD with the installation program to our customer. We had the request to create a `MSI` file.

**I am looking for a MSI tool that simply create/copy a folder on the `C:\`.**

In the best scenario the solution would be an application that we only have to install. We do not want to program it all.

Comment: No such thing as a simple tool to create MSIs. Also I don't know what you mean. Folders don't have rights. Users have rights. So a user may or may not have admin rights.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Good point on the folder write. Will edit the question.

Comment: Referring at the above requirement, I would say its quite easy to accomplish with a couple of MSI authoring tools. I recommend Advanced Installer, as what you need can be accomplished even with the free version. It also has a lot of wizards to assist you through creating the projects.  http://www.advancedinstaller.com/

Comment: I don't see a real question here.  It sounds like you need to create an installer but the questions of what the tool should be and what *all* of the requirements for the installer and how to implement them are discrete questions.  Perhaps you need a consultant to help you with this project.

Comment: [**Most common MSI tools**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50225031/windows-service-not-shown-in-add-remove-programs-under-control-panel/50229840#50229840).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [WiX toolset](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) with the help of [WiX Tutorial](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/). It should be quite easy to make a simple installation.

And don't forget to think about Upgrade policy: whether the installed package should be automatically updated with a newer one.

Comment: I really recommend to read this tutorial first, it's really easy and understandable http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/105638/A-quick-introduction-Create-an-MSI-installer-with

Comment: easy and understandable - just like piglatin spoken thru a cheese grater.

Answer (score 1):

Better approach will be to use [ClickOne](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e.aspx) for automatic application updates or something similar.

Comment: Except that the end user requested MSI presumably so that they can integrate with their deployment tools

Comment: MSI is for initial install or reinstall, but I think updates should be handled be handled automatical,

Comment: No, msi can be used for all forms of deployment.